# Adding To an External Database in Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I am new to Android programming and I am trying to take user input and add it to my external database.  Right now my php code is:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host","login","pass") or die ("Unable to connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db("database");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Table (number, format, name, price) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['number1']."', ".$_REQUEST['format1'].", ".$_REQUEST['name1'].", ".$_REQUEST['price1'].")");

mysql_close();
```

?>

I don't see anything wrong with my php, but when I run my program I am not getting any errors, but when I look at my database nothing seems to be actually getting added.  My Java code is:

```
Log.d("debug", "ENTER METHOD ADD");
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        EditText eNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.barcodeEdit);
        EditText eFormat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeFormatEdit);
        EditText eName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEdit);
        EditText ePrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.priceEdit);

        Log.d("debugNumber", eNumber.getText().toString());
        Log.d("debugFormat", eFormat.getText().toString());
        Log.d("debugName", eName.getText().toString());
        Log.d("debugPrice", ePrice.getText().toString());

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number1", eNumber.getText().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format1", eFormat.getText().toString())); //you can add as many you need
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", eName.getText().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price1", ePrice.getText().toString()));

        try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://MY_SITE.com/my.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                //is = entity.getContent();
                Log.d("debug", "ENDED TRY");
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("log_tag", e.toString());
                //return false;
                //Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

That is the bit of code that does my adding.  I know I can connect to the database fine, since the code I use to search the database works correctly, but for some reason my add is messed up.  I have the code running in a new thread since I learned the other day that you cannot do these http requests in the main thread of the program.  I have been looking all over for an answer and have yet to find one, maybe I am just missing a line, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your PHP script receiving the correct values?

Comment: I believe so, I have those Log.d commands to make sure im parsing the right values from the text boxes, is there a way to actually see what is being sent to the PHP script?  I guess I can print out what is being stored in number1, format1, etc. in my php script?

Comment: do quoting on all string vars `'".$_REQUEST['name1']."'` and use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements. Don't pass the request directly into the query. You are open to sql injections.

Comment: try [this](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/03/sqlite-databases-with-external-db.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to develop a simple html form first to make sure you don't get any problems at your php side like this.

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
   <head >
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
      <title >Form Page: sampleform</title>
   </head>
<body>
<h1>Sample form page</h1>

<form id='sampleform' method='post' action='http://MY_SITE.com/my.php' >
   <p>
   number1: <input type='text' name='number1' />
   </p>
   <p>
   format1: <input type='text' name='format1' />

   </p>

    <p>
   name1: <input type='text' name='name1' />
   </p>

    <p>
   price1: <input type='text' name='price1' />
   </p>

   <p>
   <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
   </p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Run this quick test and let me know. So that I might help you further.

**EDIT:**

Yes. The problem might be in your insert statement. Try with the following code.

```
   <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("Your host", "Db username", "Db password", "Db name");

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Couldn't connect to database";
    }

    $number = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['number1']);
    $format= $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['format1']);
    $name= $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name1']);
    $price= $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['price1']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO Table (number, format, name, price) VALUES('$number','$format','$name', '$price');";

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

if($result)
{
        echo "Successfully inserted";
}

   ?>
```

Comment: I ran this code and when I hit submit, it just printed the items, probably from the echo statements I have in my php code, I wrote in the text box and nothing was actually added to the database.  But, since the correct items were printed that should mean that the php code is receiving the correct information right?  There could be something wrong with my INSERT statement, since the php is getting the right information

Comment: It would have been better if you had gotten back to me a bit quickly . Anyways Edited my answer. Check it and let me know quickly.

Comment: That fixed it :D  Why could I have not done it with my original intsert?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is showing no error in code. To debug more line by line you should modify your PHP code and try -

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host","login","pass") or die ("Unable to connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db("database");

echo $_REQUEST['number1'];
echo $_REQUEST['format1'];
echo $_REQUEST['name1'];
echo $_REQUEST['price1'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Table (number, format, name, price) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['number1']."', '".$_REQUEST['format1']."', '".$_REQUEST['name1']."', '".$_REQUEST['price1']."')";

echo $sql;

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();
?>
```

Also you can try with $_POST syntax  instead of $_REQUEST.

You should understand the error by this.

Please share with us the result, so that we can help you further.

Thanks

Comment: When I run the android app, and refresh my php page should something be printed on the page, because nothing seems to be echoing onto the webpage.